# Error while running bundle update after doing git clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using window operating system for ruby on rails application.
I just clone the git repository which is a ruby on rails application. But, when I do bundle update it shows this error
libv8-node 15.14.0.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
bundle update
Fetching https://github.com/mimemagicrb/mimemagic.git
Fetching https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies................
Using rake 13.0.4 (was 13.0.3)
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.9 (was 1.1.8)
Using i18n 1.8.10
Using minitest 5.14.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.9
Using activesupport 5.1.7
Using builder 3.2.4
Using erubi 1.10.0
Using racc 1.5.2
Using nokogiri 1.11.7 (x64-mingw32) (was 1.11.2)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.10.0 (was 2.9.0)
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
Using actionview 5.1.7
Using rack 2.2.3
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 5.1.7
Using nio4r 2.5.7
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.5
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using actioncable 5.1.7
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 5.1.7
Using mini_mime 1.1.0
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 5.1.7
Using activemodel 5.1.7
Using arel 8.0.0
Using activerecord 5.1.7
Using public_suffix 4.0.6
Using addressable 2.8.0 (was 2.7.0)
Using execjs 2.8.1 (was 2.7.0)
Using autoprefixer-rails 10.2.5.1 (was 10.2.4.0)
Using awesome_print 1.9.2
Using bcrypt 3.1.16
Using method_source 1.0.0
Using thor 1.1.0
Using railties 5.1.7
Using best_in_place 3.0.3
Using bindex 0.8.1
Using popper_js 1.16.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.11.0 (was 0.10.4)
Using ffi 1.15.3 (x64-mingw32) (was 1.15.0)
Using rb-inotify 0.10.1
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.7.4
Using bootstrap 4.1.3
Using bundler 1.17.3
Using byebug 11.1.3
Using xpath 3.2.0
Using capybara 2.18.0
Using mini_magick 4.11.0
Using ruby-vips 2.1.2 (was 2.1.0)
Using image_processing 1.12.1
Using marcel 1.0.1
Using ssrf_filter 1.0.7
Using carrierwave 2.2.2 (was 2.2.1)
Using chartkick 4.0.5 (was 3.4.2)
Using childprocess 3.0.0
Using chronic 0.10.2
Using chunky_png 1.4.0
Using cocoon 1.2.15
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using copy_carrierwave_file 1.3.0
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using responders 3.0.1
Using warden 1.2.9
Using devise 4.8.0 (was 4.7.3)
Using devise_invitable 2.0.5 (was 2.0.3) from https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable.git (at master@db1f065)
Using dotenv 2.7.6
Using dotenv-rails 2.7.6
Using exception_notification 4.4.3
Using excon 0.84.0 (was 0.79.0)
Using faker 2.18.0 (was 2.17.0)
Using faraday-em_http 1.0.0
Using faraday-em_synchrony 1.0.0
Using faraday-excon 1.1.0
Using faraday-httpclient 1.0.1
Using faraday-net_http 1.0.1
Using faraday-net_http_persistent 1.1.0
Using faraday-patron 1.0.0
Using multipart-post 2.1.1
Using ruby2_keywords 0.0.4
Using faraday 1.5.0 (was 1.3.0)
Using formatador 0.3.0 (was 0.2.5)
Using mime-types-data 3.2021.0704 (was 3.2021.0225)
Using mime-types 3.3.1
Using fog-core 2.2.4 (was 2.2.3)
Using multi_json 1.15.0
Using fog-json 1.2.0
Using fog-xml 0.1.3
Using ipaddress 0.8.3
Using fog-aws 3.10.0
Using font-awesome-rails 4.7.0.7
Using groupdate 5.2.2
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.2
Using rails 5.1.7
Using invisible_captcha 2.0.0
Using jbuilder 2.11.2
Using jquery-rails 4.4.0
Using jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
Using jwt 2.2.3 (was 2.2.2)
Using kaminari-core 1.2.1
Using kaminari-actionview 1.2.1
Using kaminari-activerecord 1.2.1
Using kaminari 1.2.1
Fetching libv8-node 15.14.0.1
Installing libv8-node 15.14.0.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/libv8-node-15.14.0.1/ext/libv8-node
C:/Ruby27-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r
./siteconf20210707-3776-1v98cj2.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/libv8-node-15.14.0.1/ext/libv8-node/builder.rb:12:in 
`build_libv8!': failed to download node 15.14.0 (Libv8::Node::BuilderError)
from
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/libv8-node-15.14.0.1/ext/libv8-node/location.rb:30:in
`install!'
        from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'
==== in
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/libv8-node-15.14.0.1/ext/libv8-node
==== running
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/libv8-node-15.14.0.1/libexec/download-node

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/libv8-node-15.14.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.7.0/libv8-node-15.14.0.1/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing libv8-node (15.14.0.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8-node -v '15.14.0.1' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mini_racer was resolved to 0.4.0, which depends on
    libv8-node
```

Here are the versions that I'm using

```
Rails 6.1.4
ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [x64-mingw32]
Bundler version 2.2.21
```

When I do bundle install it shows this,

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby ":
  In Gemfile:
    ruby

    spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0) was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0) was resolved to 3.1.5, which depends on
        rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7) was resolved to 0.10.1, which depends on
          ffi (~> 1.0) was resolved to 1.15.0, which depends on
            ruby  (< 3.1.dev, >= 2.3) x64-mingw32

    capybara (~> 2.13) was resolved to 2.18.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3) was resolved to 1.11.2, which depends on
        ruby  (< 3.1.dev, >= 2.5) x64-mingw32

    pg (~> 0.18) was resolved to 0.21.0, which depends on
      ruby  (< 2.5, >= 2.0) x64-mingw32

Could not find gem 'ruby  (< 2.5, >= 2.0)', which is required by gem 'pg (~>
0.18)', in any of the relevant sources:
  the local ruby installation
```

Here is the gem file,

```
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
# gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
rails_version = "~> 5.1.4"
gem "activesupport",  rails_version
gem  "actionpack",    rails_version
gem  "actionview",    rails_version
gem  "activemodel",   rails_version
gem  "activerecord",  rails_version
gem  "activejob",     rails_version
gem  "actioncable",   rails_version
gem  "railties",      rails_version

gem "sprockets-rails", ">= 2.0.0"
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'mimemagic', github: 'mimemagicrb/mimemagic', ref: '01f92d86d15d85cfd0f20dabd025dcbd36a8a60f'
gem 'awesome_print', require: 'ap'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rqrcode'
gem 'devise'
gem 'faker'
gem 'kaminari'
gem "chartkick"
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'rubyzip', require: 'zip'
gem 'pdfkit', require: 'pdfkit'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'zip_tricks'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem "cocoon"
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'devise_invitable', github: 'scambra/devise_invitable'
gem 'invisible_captcha'
gem 'mini_racer'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'copy_carrierwave_file'

##SMS stuff
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'whenever'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: looks like the `pg` gem could use some updating (your ruby version is 2.7 yet the ruby version require by the gem is <2.5) either this or downgrading he your current ruby version

Comment: You mention using Rails 6.1 in your question, but the version of Rails in the Gemfile is 5.1.4. The recommended ruby version for that version of Rails is 2.5 and the max supported version is 2.6 (I believe). So, your best next step is to install an older version of ruby (check out rbenv or rvm, which help manage multiple ruby versions). It's a also a good idea to specify the ruby version in the Gemfile, which helps identify mismatches in expectation when running `bundle install`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pg` gem version is 0.8 which requires ruby < 2.5

If you want to use with ruby > 2.5 you will have to upgrade the pg gem.

You can use [RailsBump](https://railsbump.org/) to check for all the supported version for any particular gem